# What is the correct way to handle ajax events with MVC controller in ExtJs

Tags: extjs

We are trying to build a simple prototype to consume our data service using ExtJs (also to learn ExtJs at the same time).

While developing the prototype (with basic knowledge on ExtJS), I encountered several hickups.  Before I post questions, I would like to have you to take a quick look at the following.

The following is the main class which interacts with the service.  We wanted to make sure that certain UI components are masked/unmasked during ajax communications.

```
Ext.define('Sample.provider.SvcClient', {

TestConnectivity: function(prms){
    debugger;
    
    Ext.Ajax.on('beforerequest', function(conn,o,result) {
        prms.BeforeRequest(conn,o,result);
    });

    Ext.Ajax.on('requestcomplete',function(conn,o,result) {
        prms.RequestComplete(conn,o,result);
    });

    Ext.Ajax.on('requestexception',function(conn,o,result) {
        prms.RequestException(conn,o,result);
    });

    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: prms.Url,
        method: prms.HttpMethod,
        headers: {
            'Authorization' : 'Basic ' + prms.Credentials
        },
        success: prms.Success,
        failure: prms.Failure,
        callback: prms.Callback
    });
}
```

});

We developed an extension to SvcClient especially to help masking of controls during ajax communications:

```
Ext.define('Sample.util.ClientProxy', {

CtlToMask : null,

DoTestConnection: function(ctlToMask, callback, url, userName, pwd) {
    debugger;
    var proxy = this;
    proxy.CtlToMask = ctlToMask;
        
        var client = new Sample.provider.SvcClient();
        var params = {
            Url: url,
            HttpMethod: "GET",
            Credentials: Sample.util.Conversions.Base64.encode(userName + ":" + pwd),
            CtlToMask: proxy.CtlToMask,
            Scope:proxy,
            BeforeRequest: function(conn,o,result,Scope) {
                debugger;
                if(Scope.CtlToMask !=null) {                        
                    if(Scope.CtlToMask.getEl() != undefined)
                        Scope.CtlToMask.getEl().mask('Testing Connectivity...', 'x-mask-loading');                    
                    else
                        Scope.CtlToMask.mask('Testing Connectivity...', 'x-mask-loading');                    
                }
            },                
            RequestComplete: function(conn,o,result) {
                if(this.CtlToMask !=null) {
                    if(this.CtlToMask.getEl() != undefined)
                        this.CtlToMask.getEl().unmask(true);                  
                    else
                        this.CtlToMask.unmask(true);                
                }                    
            },
            RequestException: function(conn,o,result) {
                if(this.CtlToMask !=null) {
                    if(this.CtlToMask.getEl() != undefined)
                        this.CtlToMask.getEl().unmask(true);                  
                    else
                        this.CtlToMask.unmask(true);                
                }
            }                                  
        };

        
        client.TestConnectivity(params);   

}
```

});

I have the controller as shown below:

```
Ext.define('Sample.controller.Locations', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

models: ['Location', 'Country'],

views: [
    'portal.location.Menu',
    'portal.location.Edit'
],

init: function() {
    this.control({
        'locationsMenu':{
            OpenAddNewSvcPopup: this.OnOpenAddNewSvcPopup
        },
        'locationsEdit':{
            TestSvcConnectivity: this.OnTestSvcConnectivity,
            render: function () { },
            afterrender: function () { },
            boxready: function () { }  
        }
    });
},

OnOpenAddNewSvcPopup: function(){       
    var newLoc = Ext.create('Sample.model.Location', {
        UserName: 'admin',
        Uri: 'http://localhost/DataServicesBase/Data.svc'
    });
    var v = Ext.create('widget.locationsEdit',{ mode:'add'});
    v.down('form').loadRecord(newLoc);
},

OnTestSvcConnectivity: function(ctl){

    var proxy = new Sample.util.ClientProxy();
    proxy.DoTestConnection(
        ctl,
        this.OnTestSvcConnectivityCallback,
        ctl.down("#Uri").value + '/Countries',
        ctl.down("#UserName").value,
        ctl.down("#Password").value
        );           
},

OnTestSvcConnectivityCallback: function(options,success,result){
    if(success) {
        //show the result
    }
    else {
             //Show error in window           
    }
}
```

});

The view would look like the following:

```
Ext.define('Sample.view.portal.location.Edit', {
extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
alias: 'widget.locationsEdit',

//title: 'Edit Service Location',
layout: 'fit',
autoShow: true,
title: 'Edit Service Location',
bodyStyle: 'border:0px',
closeAction:'destroy',

config:{        
    mode: 'edit'
},

constructor: function(configs){
    this.callParent(arguments);        
    this.initConfig(configs);
    if(this.mode == "add") this.setTitle('Add New Service Location');
},

initComponent: function() {

    this.items = [
        {
            xtype: 'form',                
            items: [
                {
                    xtype:          'textfield',
                    name:           'Id',
                    itemId:         'Id',
                    fieldLabel:     'Unique Name',
                    labelStyle:     'font-weight:bold',
                    allowBlank:     false,
                    maxLength:      64,
                    width:          300
                },
                {
                    xtype:          'textfield',
                    name :          'Uri',
                    itemId:         'Uri',
                    fieldLabel:     'URI',
                    maxLength:      300,
                    width:          500,
                    allowBlank:     false
                },
                {
                    xtype:          'textfield',
                    name :          'UserName',
                    itemId:         'UserName',
                    fieldLabel:     'User Name',
                    allowBlank:     false,
                    maxLength:      64,
                    width:          200
                },
                {
                    xtype:          'textfield',
                    name :          'Password',
                    itemId:         'Password',
                    fieldLabel:     'Password',
                    allowBlank:     false,
                    maxLength:      64,
                    width:          200
                }                    
            ],
            bodyStyle: 'padding:5px;'
        }
    ];

    this.buttons = [
        {
            text:       'Test Connectivity',
            action:     'test',
            scope:      this,
            handler:    this.OnTestSvcConnectivity
        },
        {
            text:       'Save',
            action:     'save'
        },
        {
            text:       'Cancel',
            scope:      this,
            handler:    this.close
        }
    ];
    
    this.callParent();
    this.addEvents('TestSvcConnectivity') //custom event
},

OnTestSvcConnectivity: function(){
    this.fireEvent('TestSvcConnectivity', this); //will be raised to controller
}
```

});

## Q1

The approach works fine during first time when I click on "Test Connection" button (from the popup).  If I click the same button for the second time, the (BeforeRequest) handler fires twice.  Clicking for the third time, the handler gets fired thrice.  What is the mistake in my code.

## Q2

If I cancel the popup and again click on "Test Connection" it would never work.  The handler still maintains "some" kind of reference (or state) of previous popup instance.  As it could not be found, it throws "undefine" on object members.  I confirmed this as through the debugger, I could see the id of previous popup instance instead of the current one.  The handler always tries to honor the first popup instantiated no matter what.

## Q3

Is the pattern we are trying to follow for this sample prototype is having any pitfalls/problems.  We are trying to develop using MVC features of ExtJS and ensure that we are using stand and good patterns/practices so that we will not be facing above kind of very basic issues.

Comment: looks way over engineered to me. My advice is to use the framework as is outlined in the guides and examples, then when you get a good feel for it you can go all crazy and spawn your own framework.

Comment: Also you probably need to set your service proxy to be a singleton class so that it setups the Ajax listeners only once b/c if remember correctly they are global: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?128646-Singleton-vs-class-with-all-static-members